# How to make field always valid and read only using VB script

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a case in which I have field name as Order date for which I need to make it as always valid and it should be valid always.

Below is the script I tried.

```
Public Function getFolderDetails_FromPath_ForEmailInvoice(ByVal pXDoc As CASCADELib.CscXDocument) As String

   On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

   Const cProcName = "getFolderDetails_FromPath_ForEmailInvoice"
   DbgOut(cProcName, Err, "Start")

            Dim FullPath As String
            Dim PathArry() As String
            Dim FolderName As String
            Dim FolderProp() As String
            Dim xfolder As CscXFolder
            Set xfolder = pXDoc.ParentFolder

            While Not xfolder.IsRootFolder
            Set xfolder = xfolder.ParentFolder
            Wend

                'Added below line for KTM testing
                'FullPath="F:\EmailImport\chirag@gmail.com_08-01-2014_00-00-00\Demo_Manipulados_02.TIF"

            If xfolder.XValues.ItemExists("AC_FIELD_OriginalFileName") Then

                FullPath= xfolder.XValues.ItemByName("AC_FIELD_OriginalFileName").Value

            End If

            PathArry() = Split(FullPath,"\")

            FolderName = PathArry(UBound(PathArry())-1)

            FolderProp() = Split(FolderName,"_")


            If CInt(UBound(FolderProp()))=2 Then
               If(ValidateEmailAddress(FolderProp(0))) Then
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").Text = FolderProp(0)
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").ForcedValid = True
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("ReceiveDate").Text = FolderProp(1)
                  ValidationForm.Fields.ItemByName("ReceiveDate").Enabled = False
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("ReceiveDate").OriginalValid = True

                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").Text = FolderProp(2)
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").ForcedValid = True
               Else
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").Text = ""
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").ForcedValid = True
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").Text = ""
                  pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").ForcedValid = True



               End If

            Else
               pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").Text = ""
               pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_ID").ForcedValid = True
               pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").Text = ""
               pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").ForcedValid = True

            End If
```

Comment: That's not VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this property to make field valid always true:

```
pXDoc.Fields.ItemByName("Email_Time").ExtractionConfident = True
```